# calling executable from Python Win32 IDLE works but the same from Windows console Python session doesn't

Tags: python, console, subprocess, runtime-error, executable

I am trying to run an executable file from Python using os.system or subprocess, in my Windows machine, but I have a strange problem.

The os.system/subprocess call works fine with: 
32-bit Python console from IDLE,

but but it doesn't work from: 
1) The cmd if I run any Python session (32 or 64)
2) If I use any Python version from Spyder.
3) PyCharm with any Python version;

and I get these errors:

[1. Run time error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yNmb.png)

[2. An error window that appears immediately after I click OK on the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgcWL.png)

I've spent many hours on this, but I am unable to figure out why this happens. Why wont subprocess or os.system work the same from difference Python consoles?

The dependencies of this application are:
GDAL 201 (MSVC 2013) for 32 bit Windows PC,
GDAL 201 (MSVC 2013 Win 64) for 64 bit Windows PC,
GDAL 2.1.0 for Python 2.7,
Microsoft MPI v7.1,
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package (x86),
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package (x64)

> sys.path - Python2.7 (Win32) IDLE

['', 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ArcGIS\Python 2.7', 
'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\idlelib', 
'C:\Users\svimal\Desktop\Python', 
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\python27.zip', 
'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\DLLs', 
'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib', 
'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\plat-win', 
'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\lib-tk', 
'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2', 
'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages', 
'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin', 
'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy', 
'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts']

> sys.path Python console from Windows CMD

['', 'C:\Users\svimal\Desktop\Python', 
'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\python27.zip', 
'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\DLLs', 
'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib', 
'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\plat-win',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\lib-tk', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\FontTools', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\win32', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg']

> sys.path - PyCharm

['C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev',
 'C:\Users\svimal\Desktop\Python',
 'C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\python27.zip',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\DLLs',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\plat-win',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\lib-tk',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\FontTools',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\win32',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions',
 'C:\Users\svimal\Desktop\Work\EU_Floods']

> sys.path - Spyder

['', 'C:\Users\svimal\Desktop\Python', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\python27.zip', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\DLLs', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\plat-win', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\lib-tk', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\FontTools', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\win32', 
 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg']

Comment: check the `sys.path` within process itself. and at all you have to investigate the different between PyCharm and IDLE. Adding `shell=True` is subprocess may help.

Comment: And please include `WHAT YOU TRIED OUT` in your post.

Comment: I've added the sys.path from the different Python consoles mentioned in the post.

The exact command that I use is os.system("path\executable.exe")

Comment: Try `subprocess.call('path/to/app.exe', shell=True)`

Comment: I've tried that, does not help!

Answer (score 0):

you may perhaps retry after using "script\make_winpython_fix.bat", but winpython-2.7.9.5 didn't have that option, (that came  october 8th 2015)

https://github.com/stonebig/winpython/commit/1080831930a1dedaf6a0c3019e7150b46a138357

Comment: How do I use winpython_fix.bat? I reinstalled the latest version of winpython, and now the command line python session seems to work as expected. But Spyder is still throwing the runtime error. I am yet to check PyCharm.

Comment: you double-click on the script "make_winpython_fix.bat"

Comment: Did that. Doesn't fix the issue. However, I copied the make_winpython_fix.bat file from the scripts folder of the new version of WinpPython (WinPython-64bit-2.7.12) to the same folder in the installed version (2.7.9) in my computer. I could try installing the new version and running make_winpython_fix.bat again.